# Expected distribution of the difference of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

There are two random variables $X$ and $Y$ PDF's $f(x)$ and $g(y)$. Both distributions functions have the same support [a,b], where $0<a<b<\infty$.  Realizations of the variables are observed "ex-post." "Ex-iterim" the following holds: $E[X] = E[Y]$.  I wish to find "ex-ante" $\Pr[X-Y<0]$ .

My attempt: $\Pr[X<Y] = \int_a^b F(y)g(y)dy$.  Is it true ex-ante?

Comment: What do you mean by the "cdf (or pdf) of $Z$ in expectation"?

Comment: As @carmichael561 points out, the random variable is $Z$; the cdf or pdf of $Z$ are just honest-to-goodness functions, they have "no randomness of their own."

Comment: @carmichael561 Maybe the following particular example may help to understand the problem: There are two agents (1 and 2) both of whom independently choose a number between 0 and 1 randomly. The realization is ex post. The choice of a number of agent 1 is dictated by pdf f and that of agent  2 is dictated by g, and in expectation (which is ex interim) they draw the same number.  Lets say I would like to find out the probability that agent 1 draws a number higher than agent 2 (from ex ante point).  Hope this makes sense

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the conditional CDF or pdf?

Comment: @carmichael561 No, not for conditional.  I have these three periods: ex post, ex interim, and ex ante.  Ex interim they draw the same number, and I have been wondering what happens ex ante

Comment: Some of the language used in the comments suggests this is a game theory problem. Even so, I am finding it hard to reconcile some of the language. Explanations of what the problem is about should be edited into the question, not posted as comments; also make sure the language you use says what you mean it to say. By the way, the probability that agent 1 draws higher than agent 2 is P(X-Y>0), so looking at X+Y seems to be relatively useless in that case.

Comment: @DavidK I reformulated the question

Answer (score 0):

The respective cdf of $X$ and $Y$ are 
$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt
\\G(y) = \int_{-\infty}^y g(u)\,du
$$
For $x+y\leq z$ we need $y\leq z-x$. Therefore, the cdf of $Z\equiv X+Y$ is
$$H(z) = \int_{x=-\infty}^x f(t) \int_{y=-\infty}^{z-x}g(u)\,du \,dt
$$
The expectation value of $Z$ is
$$
E[Z]\,\, = \int_{t=-\infty}^x f(t) \int_{u=-\infty}^{z-t}g(u) (t+u) \,du \,dt
$$
The trick to show that $E[Z] = E[X]+ E[Y]$ is to note that you can reverse the order to say that also
$$
E[Z]\,\, = \int_{u=-\infty}^x g(u) \int_{t=-\infty}^{z-u}f(t) (t+u) \,dt \,du
$$
and a bit of integration by parts gives the result.

However, this trick and the IBP is valid only if $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ meet certain fairly reasonable conditions.  In particular, it is valid if $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ each have finite second moments.